# Using FlatFileItem writer in multithreaded step

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-batch

I am a little bit confused when reading spring documentation about FlatFileItemWriter they say that it's not thread safe so i was thinking about wrapping it into a SynchronizedItemStreamWriter but in this link https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/SynchronizedItemStreamWriter.html they say : For example, **using a FlatFileItemWriter in a multi-threaded step does NOT require synchronizing writes.**
Any explination please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thread safety in Spring Batch file writers is related to two aspects: updating the execution context and writing to the output file. Those are two different things and should be carefully considered when using those writers in a multi-threaded step. I will explain both aspects separately.

#### 1. Thread safety with regards to execution context updates

For restartability reasons, file writers (flat file, json, xml, etc) update the execution context with a key named `current.count`. This key is used in a restart scenario to know how many items were written in the previous run and truncate the file to the last known correct offset. If you use such a writer in a multi-threaded context, this key can be overridden by different threads using a shared writer, which is problematic. That's why it is recommended to turn-off state management in such scenarios by using the `saveState` flag. More details on this in the [Multi-threaded Step](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/scalability.html#multithreadedStep) section.

#### 2. Thread safety with regards to writing to the output file

Writing data to a structured JSON or XML file is different than writing to a flat file. If you use a non-synchronized `JsonItemWriter` or `StaxEventItemWriter` in a multi-threaded step, the output of one thread can override the one of another thread and you would end up with an incorrect output file. Here is a quick example with the `StaxEventItemWriter`:

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.builder.JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.builder.FlatFileItemWriterBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.SynchronizedItemStreamReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.SynchronizedItemStreamWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.xml.builder.StaxEventItemWriterBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabase;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;
import org.springframework.oxm.Marshaller;
import org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJobConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SynchronizedItemStreamReader<Person> itemReader() {
        String sql = "select * from person";
        JdbcCursorItemReader<Person> personItemReader = new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<Person>()
                .name("personItemReader")
                .dataSource(dataSource())
                .sql(sql)
                .beanRowMapper(Person.class)
                .build();
        SynchronizedItemStreamReader<Person> synchronizedItemStreamReader = new SynchronizedItemStreamReader<>();
        synchronizedItemStreamReader.setDelegate(personItemReader);
        return synchronizedItemStreamReader;
    }

//  @Bean
//  public SynchronizedItemStreamWriter<Person> itemWriter() {
//      Jaxb2Marshaller marchaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
//      marchaller.setClassesToBeBound(Person.class);
//      StaxEventItemWriter<Person> personStaxEventItemWriter = new StaxEventItemWriterBuilder<Person>()
//              .name("personItemWriter")
//              .resource(new FileSystemResource("persons.xml"))
//              .marshaller(marchaller)
//              .rootTagName("persons")
//              .build();
//      SynchronizedItemStreamWriter<Person> synchronizedItemStreamWriter = new SynchronizedItemStreamWriter<>();
//      synchronizedItemStreamWriter.setDelegate(personStaxEventItemWriter);
//      return synchronizedItemStreamWriter;
//  }

    @Bean
    public StaxEventItemWriter<Person> itemWriter() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marchaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marchaller.setClassesToBeBound(Person.class);
        return new StaxEventItemWriterBuilder<Person>()
                .name("personItemWriter")
                .resource(new FileSystemResource("persons.xml"))
                .marshaller(marchaller)
                .rootTagName("persons")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobs, StepBuilderFactory steps) {
        return jobs.get("job")
                .start(steps.get("step")
                        .<Person, Person>chunk(5)
                        .reader(itemReader())
                        .writer(itemWriter())
                        .taskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor())
                        .build())
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyJobConfiguration.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        EmbeddedDatabase embeddedDatabase = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
                .addScript("/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-hsqldb.sql")
                .build();
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(embeddedDatabase);
        jdbcTemplate.execute("create table person (id int primary key, name varchar(20));");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            jdbcTemplate.execute(String.format("insert into person values (%s, 'foo%s');", i, i));
        }
        return embeddedDatabase;
    }

    @XmlRootElement
    static class Person {
        private int id;
        private String name;

        public Person() {
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "Person{id=" + id + ", name='" + name + '\'' + '}';
        }
    }

}
```

This example reads items from a database table and writes them to a file. With a non synchronized writer, the sample produces the following `persons.xml` file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<persons>
    <name>foo7</name>
</person><name>foo5</name><id/></id>><idson<name>foo7</name></person><name>
foo5
</name><id/></id><name>foo7</name></person><name>foo9</name></person><name>
foo7
</name></person><name>foo5
</name><id/></id>e></id></person></persons></person>><id>6</id><person>
<id>9</id>
<name>foo6</name>
</name><person>
<id>10</id>
<name>foo10</name>
</person></persons>
```

This is obviously incorrect. With a synchronized writer, the output file is correctly generated. This issue does not happen with a `FlatFileItemWriter` even if it is not sychnronized, because flat files do not contain extra XML elements to open/close tags or JSON elements like `[]` and `,` to delimit arrays and objects. So there is no need to synchronize writes in this case. This is what is described in the Javadoc of the `SynchronizedItemStreamWriter`:

```
This decorator is useful when using a non thread-safe item writer in a multi-threaded
step. Typical delegate examples are the JsonFileItemWriter and StaxEventItemWriter.

It should be noted that synchronizing writes might introduce some performance
degradation, so this decorator should be used wisely and only when necessary.
For example, using a FlatFileItemWriter in a multi-threaded step does NOT
require synchronizing writes, so using this decorator in such use case might
be counter productive.
```